# Deployment solution using stsadm

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, stsadm

I have a solution with 4 projects to automatically some processes in Sharepoint.these projects are:

- WebPartProject: Create a custom webpart
- CreateTemplate: Create 2 documents libraries (with columns), a simple List (and columns) and a Page to put WebPartProject's webpart and the previously document libraries and the simple list in this page.
- WorkflowOne: Put a workflow in one of the previous document library
- WorkflowTwo: Put another workflow in the same document library that previously.

So, When I deploy this solution in VS, everything works.... But When I try to deploy this solution using powershell, doesn't work.

I use the following scripts:

- stsadm -o addsolution -filename CreateTemplateSolution.wsp ------> Operation completed succesfuly
- stsadm -o deploysolution -name CreateTemplateSolution.wsp -immediate -allowGacDeployment ------> Timer job successfully created

And when I go to Site Actions --> Site Settings --> Site Actions --> Manage site features, I can find my solution, I put his status to Activated, restart IIS.... But When I open Sharepoint, I can't find anything.... :(. Am I missing something?????

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to force the timer jobs execution :

```
stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
```

stsadm is deprecated inside SharePoint 2010.

Use Powershell instead.

[A good strating point here !](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/12/02/adding-and-deploying-solutions-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Thanks you Le_Fredo. I used your command and Activate this feature manually in Sharepoint site too and It's done!!!!